# jquery and ruby on rails insert variable inside on click post

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, variables, post

Im having this code

```
  %button.aristo-default.accept{:href => "#", :onclick => "$.post('/sessions/accept_invite', { user_id: 1, friend_id: 1 }) " }
```

Would like to place @friend.id inside the 1's so I can have variables instead of the hardcoded 1, what would be the way to do it? must be simple but I tried several ways to no avail. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#{@friend.id}` to get the actual value:

```
%button.aristo-default.accept{:href => "#", :onclick => "$.post('/sessions/accept_invite', { user_id: 1, friend_id: #{@friend.id} }) " }
```

Comment: Thx I knew it was some simple escaping thingy a bit mixed up between different programming languages coudent come up with it thx